# Email App for Exchange Server and alternatives

Tags: email

I would like to set-up my company email in the Email app on my android device (Exchange server). After completing the set-up, it asked me for security update in which it lists lots of warnings such as erasing all the data on phone, etc. I got scared from these as I am not sure whether the IT dept would have all those privileges on phone or not.

Alternatively, I tried to set up an alias with my Gmail account to send email from my Gmail and it looks like it was sent from my company email, but I don't have the SMTP server address (I tried my best to get it, it seems that the exchange server doesn't have one).

Any alternative to use my company email on my android without give all these permissions to take control of my phone without my knowledge?

My phone is Samsung S3 GT-I9300 with Android 4.3

Comment: What phone do you have (Brand, model, android version)?

Comment: My phone is Samsung S3 GT-I9300 with Android 4.3

Answer (score 1):

The security requirements set by the Exchange server admins are designed to protect their company information. They don't want to risk you losing your phone and having any random person read your company email. If a thief tries to brute-force the lock code, the email program will force a factory reset after a certain number of failures.

Personally, I think if they require you to read email outside of work hours (yuck) and have this security requirement, they should be willing to provide a phone and service for free. But I digress.

Here are some solutions you can try:

### Email app that lies about complience

There are some email apps that will lie to the Exchange server about its adherence to the requested policies. I use [Enhanced Email](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.qs.enhancedemail&hl=en). It's a paid app, but it was a Free App of the Day on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0052TS8OY) a couple years ago. There's also [K-9](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fsck.k9&hl=en), a free and open source app, but it only works with specific Exchange servers (2003/2007). There are probably others out there that work as well.

### XPosed Module

The XPosed has a ton of modules for system tweaks, including one that should let you [bypass Exchange Security Requirements](http://repo.xposed.info/module/org.flacid.exchangebypass). It will let you bypass the requirement while using any email app you want.